# Is it possible to bypass default 404 behaviour for ParamConverter with null values?

Tags: 8, routes

When [upcasting route parameters](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122223) drupal will automatically generate 404 page if `ParamConverterInterface::convert()` service returns `null`. Is it possible to override this behaviour and allow null values?

For example I'd like to load custom entity for a specific route however in case the entity doesn't exist, I'd still like to execute my controller code that will deal with null value on it's own.

With default 404 getting in my way, I can't use `ParamConverter` service and I have to load entity manually inside controller which is ugly.

Comment: Sounds like a good example bad design. Try to refactor your code and use different approach to what you'e trying to do.

Comment: @IvanJaros Consider for example AJAX requests or REST API calls. In these cases you'd rather like to return some meaningful response to the caller instead of rendering standard 404 page with full HTML source and styles.

Comment: Then do the conversion in your controller.

Comment: @IvanJaros That's what I'm doing now, but it's ugly solution. Ideally `ParamConverterInterface` could provide additional method like `allowNull()` or something like that. But since it doesn't I could always swap `paramconverter_manager` service but that's even worse idea. Apparently the only reason why 404 is generated is because `ParamConverterManager::convert()` throws `ParamNotConvertedException` if the `ParamConverterInterface::convert()` returns `null`. And this is to me is bad design because it assumes that `null` is "bad" value which might not be true in some scenarios.